# how do I increase the accuracy of redis hyperloglog

Tags: redis, hyperloglog

I am using a very simple implementation of redis HLL

PFADD to add the elements and PFCOUNT ( something with PFMERGE ) to get the count

Is there a way I can tune the efficiency of redis HLL , by increasing memory allocated etc

Answer (score 0):

NO, you CANNOT. The size of a hyperloglog is hard coded, and you cannot change it by configuration or compile-time options. If you do need to change it, you have to modify the source code and build it by yourself.

```
// hyperloglog.c

#define HLL_P 14 /* The greater is P, the smaller the error. */
```

Also, the greater is P, the more memory it costs.

Comment: I would anyway have very few HLL keys ,  So memory is not the problem 

Should I increase the HLL_P size then. 
What should I keep it as ?

Comment: I tried to recompile with HLL_P 28  ... but make test fails

Comment: Of course the test will fail, since you've changed the precision. You should also modify the test code if you want to pass the test. Or write your own test cases.